# Different outputs for same seed in MT Implementation in PHP vs Javascript

Tags: php, algorithm, mersenne-twister

I am trying to implement **Mersenne Twister** algorithm in PHP. I have taken the Javascript implementation from http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/JAVASCRIPT/java-script.html

I have almost made a line to line conversion from the above js code. But, the random number generated for a given seed is different in PHP.

Are there any specific steps to be followed when implementing in PHP (Choosing datatypes etc) ?

Code snippet as below

```
/************* PHP ***************************/


<?php

require_once "mersenne_twister.php";
use mersenne_twister\twister;

$range = array(1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,15);
$twister1 = new twister(1347299472.0059);
$t1 =  $twister1->int32()* (1.0 / 4294967296.0) ;
$foo = $t1 * count($range);
echo $foo;


/************* Javascript ***************************/

var seed = 1347299472.0059;
var range = [1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,15];// the numbers to chose from
var foo = Math.floor(genrand_float(range ) * range .length);
document.write(foo);
```

**$twister1->int32() * (1.0 / 4294967296.0)** and  **genrand_float(range)** gives different output.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [mt_rand()](http://php.net/mt_rand) function already implements the Mersenne Twister algorithm, there's no need to write your own version.

Comment: The mt_rand() function does not accept a seed value. I would need to provide a seed value of myown.

Comment: Then, you can either use `mt_srand()` or follow your original plans and reimplement everything yourself, but you'll need to provide your current code if you expect help on that.

Comment: http://kingfisher.nfshost.com/sw/twister/ is the php implementation. The javascript implementation is here @ https://gist.github.com/300494.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question and post the relevant code there. I'm not really willing to rewrite PHP builtin functions ;-)